# CSS Object-fit and aspect-ratio

Tags: css, image-resizing, aspect-ratio, object-fit

I have a small problem with css property object-fit and/or aspect-ratio.

1. Context: I have a block (a big link) containing an image and some text. The image is of unknown dimensions and aspect ratio.
2. I want to force the image dimensions, without warping it, to fit it in a display zone of known aspect ratio. Example: i want my image to be always displayed in a 4/3 zone, width 100%, max width 400px. My problem, here, is the aspect ratio, which i can't fix. I'd like that :

   - the browser view available width, and compute corresponding image width (that, no pb)
   - apply a 4/3 aspect ratio to deduce display zone height
   - display image in this zone, enlarging it if needed, while maintaining its intrinsic aspect ratio (that, no pb)

```
<a href="/foo" class="ctt">
    <picture>
        <img loading="lazy" src="foo" alt="whatever" class="ctt__img">
    </picture>
    <p class="ctt__img__titre">titre image</p>
    <p class="ctt__img__auteur">auteur image</p>
    <h3 class="ctt__titre">titre bloc</h3>
    <p class="ctt__desc">description bloc</p>
</a>
```

```
.ctt {
  display: block;
}
.ctt__img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  object-fit : cover;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you explain another way? Not sure what you're after here

Comment: Let's say i have a block which is 500px wide. That would make my image 400px wide. Then i would like my image to be displayed at 400x300px, whatever her initial dimensions. Examples : if the intrinsic dimensions of my image are 500x400 then it should be shrinked to 400x320, and cropped by object-fit cover. If it's 200x400 it should be enlarged to 400x800 and cropped. If it's 500x200 it should be enlarged to 750x300 and cropped. So the display is always of aspect-ratio 4/3, whatever the intrinsic aspect ratio.